# Opening an activity that instantly calls another activity: I don't want the first one to be seen

Tags: android

I have an application with a Main Menu to access several options. One of these options is the main option (List Tasks). This application has a log in system that works with accounts.

I want to have something like WhatsApp. In WhatsApp, when you click on a notification the conversation is shown, and when you close that conversation the activity with all your conversations is shown. I want that, when you open the application, the List Tasks activity is shown, and when you close this one you'll see the Main Menu. To do that I made MainMenuActivity to call TaskListActivity as soon as it's created.

This works fine when I open the application and I'm logged in, the user doesn't see that two activities are opened, it seems like TaskListActivity is the only one opened. But if I do it when I log in (from AccountAuthenticatorActivity), the MainMenuActivity is shown for half a sec and then the TaskListActivity is shown.

How can I fix it? I'm doing it the wrong way?

Comment: I personally think that if you need to do something like that then there is something wrong with how you designed your application. You should have code that decides which activity is going to be started in a different place so that you can use that without having to start an activity just to perform that task.

Comment: No, it isn't. It may be that under some conditions you simply "keep going" further. And sometimes it may be simplier to just extend Activity, even you do not need any UI

Answer (score 1):

Do what you need to do in onCreate() (but do not call setContentView() - it'd be pointless), fire new intent to call another activity and then call finish() to kill your "transitional" activity at the end of its onCreate(); Voila ;)

Comment: But I want that, if I close the second activity, the first one is shown. If I finish it it won't be, right? 

I tried calling startActivity from onCreate without using setContentView, but a black screen is seen half a second.

I tried to call the previous activity from onDestroy, but it doesn't work, an exception is thrown.